# Solve $\mathop{\arg\max}_{{v \in \mathbb{R}^m, \| v \| = 1}} v^T A A^T v$ with SVD

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, singular-values

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix with full rank and $m \le n$.
>   How can we solve the problem
>   $$
> \mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{v \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| v \| = 1}} v^T A A^T v
> $$
>   with singular value decomposition (instead of PCA)?
>
> *Hint: For all orthogonal matrices $Q$ have*
>   $$\mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{v \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| v \| = 1}} f(Qv) = Q^T \mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{w \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| w \| = 1}} f(w). \tag{$\star$}$$

**My idea (now with help from the comments and answers)**
Let $A = U \Sigma V^T$ bei the SVD of $A$.
Then we have
\begin{align*}
M
:=\mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{v \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| v \| = 1}} v^T A A^T v
& = \mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{v \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| v \| = 1}} v^T U \Sigma V^T V \Sigma^T U^T v
= \mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{v \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| v \| = 1}} (U^T v)^T \Sigma^2 (U^T v) \\
& \overset{(\star)}{=} U \cdot \mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{w := U^T v \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| w \| = 1}} w^T \Sigma^2 w
= U \cdot \mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\substack{w \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ \| w \| = 1}} \sum_{k = 1}^{m} (\sigma_k w_k)^2
\end{align*}
Since the singular values $(\sigma_k)_{k \in \{1, \ldots, m\}}$ are all positive and $\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2 \ge \ldots \ge \sigma_m > 0$, the argmax is attained at $w = (1, \underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{(m - 1)\text{-times}})^T$, so $M = U e_1$, which is the first left singular vector.

**Edit: Second Idea** 
Finding the argmax corresponds to finding an point of the function $f(v) = v^T A A^T v = \| v^T A \|^2$ where $f'(v) = 0$.
Can I utilise that?

Comment: Do you know about matrix norms? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: Ok, another thing: when you write $\arg\max_{v}$ it is the optimal $v$, when you write $\arg\max_{w}$ it is the optimal $w$. How come those two are equal if $w=U^Tv$? Do you see something is missing here? Compare to the hint given.

Comment: I changed variables and used $\| U^T v \| = \| v \| = 1$, like I would do normally, when handling $\max\limits_{\substack{v \in \mathbb{R^m} \\ \| v \| = 1}}$. Is that not valid for argmax?

Comment: @Ian's first comment: Why is the argmax any of the left singular vectors and why would the $w$ be a vector of the form you described? If $v$ is a left singular vector, all of it's components can be non zero and when multiplying it with the orthogonal matrix $U$, why would all entried except the first one vanish?

Comment: @Ian So this correction you are speaking of is exactly the hint? So the first term of the second row should be $U^T \cdot$ argmax $\ldots$ (everything that's already there)?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Done. Glad I could help. (Incidentally, a really great reference in general that interweaves the SVD all over the place is *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau.)

Comment: @ViktorGlombik A classic result for matrix norms is $\|A\|_2 = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|x\|_2 = 1} \|Ax\|_2 = \sigma_{max}(A)$ and it is essentially proved in the same way as was done here. Check the wiki-link I posted earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to change variables to $w=U^T v$, then you need to multiply by $U$ on the outside, in order to convert the argmax over $w$ into the argmax over $v$. Once you've done that, it should be clear that since $\sigma_1$ is the biggest, one argmax is obtained by setting $w_1=1$ and all other $w_k=0$. Thus you get $Ue_1$ which is to say the first left singular vector. (Of course $-Ue_1$ is another argmax, and there can be more of them if $\sigma_2=\sigma_1$.)

But in my view of the SVD, it is more intuitive to start from this property from scratch. That is, we define the right singular vectors $v_k$ to be some argmax of $\| Av \|$ over unit vectors orthogonal to $v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}$. We define the left singular vectors $u_k$ to be some argmax of $\| A^Tu \|$ over unit vectors orthogonal to $u_1,\dots,u_{k-1}$. Then it is a theorem that $Av_k=\sigma_k u_k$ and $A^T u_k=\sigma_k v_k$ (in particular, $A v_i$ is parallel to $u_i$ and $A^T u_i$ is parallel to $v_i$). You can then stitch these relations together into the usual $A=U \Sigma V^T$ form.

Answer (score 1):

Replace each $\sigma_k$s with the maximum of the $\sigma_k$s to get an upper bound.
That upper bound is always achievable with a particular choice of $w_k$s.

Comment: Is there any way to find a solution using my second idea?